# apache mod_rewrite rule writing

Tags: php, apache

In my application, I am trying to link `http://domain.com/auth/login` and `/auth/register` to `http://domain.com/?p=auth&action=$` where `$` is this: `http://domain.com/auth/$`

My code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^auth/(.+)$ ?p=auth&action=$1
```

but now all my css and images are messed up ._.

Comment: Look at all the content in the related section and see if you can piece it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks fine, except I would suggest using a full url instead for the redirect. And to reduce interactions with other rules you should add the `[L]` flag stopping the rewrite process for matched requests with that rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^auth/(.+)$ http://domain.com/?p=auth&action=$1 [L]
```

---

And a general hint: if you have access to the server configuration then put your rewriting rules there instead of using .htaccess style rewriting. It is more reliable and easier to configure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/auth/(.+)$ /?p=auth&action=$1 [L]
```

Or even with a slightly better performance:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/auth/(.+)$ /index.php?p=auth&action=$1 [L]
```

(I assume you use the file `index.php` as a router, might also be whatever other language or solution. )

Comment: okies, great thanks it worked. where do i put the rewrite code, then? I have access to the server configuration.

Comment: another problem is that now it just redirects to that url, not keep the /auth/whatever to the URL

Comment: Put it right above of where you configure things like the `DocumentRoot` and `Options` inside your default or virtual server configuration. You might have to use an absolute path inside the `RewriteRule` then. One further advantage: you can enable `RewriteLogging` (see the excellent manual) in case things don't work as expected.

Comment: Ah, ok, if you want to keep the URL inside the browser unchanged you have to use a path, not an url. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget: if you put those rules into the certral server configuration, then unlinke when using .htaccess files you have to restart the server process for them to be read in.

Comment: aha, I editied httpd.conf and removed the .htaccess and the rewrite stopped working. So i'll test it with the path too. thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19676/discussion-between-qaisjp-and-arkascha)

Comment: As mentioned: if you have _any_ problems with rewriting not working as expected: USE LOGGING. The rewriting module offers you the two configuration options `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`. Those are well explained in the manual. Set the level to something like 7 and watch what is logged whilst making a request. The module explains in details what is happening inside the rewriting engine. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html